# SDC constraints for two flop sychronizer

Tags: synthesis, vlsi, timing-analysis, constraints, cdc

I have doubt, What should be proper SDC constraint for CDC module, i.e., two flop synchronizer.
between "`dat` driving by `aclk` to `bdat1` driving by `bclk`"
Note: `aclk` and `bclk` are not the same, also question for what if same too?

Is it false path?

[image]

Following is SDC constraints file I have used,

```
# Input ports
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set_input_delay $ACLK_IN_DELAY  -clock $SCLK [get_ports dat ]  

set_input_delay $V_CLK_1_IN_DELAY     -clock $V_CLK_1    [get_ports srst_ni]  
set_input_delay $V_CLK_1_IN_DELAY     -clock $V_CLK_1    [get_ports drst_ni]  

# Output ports
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set_output_delay $BCLK_OUT_DELAY  -clock $DCLK [get_ports bdat2]
```

Comment: What is your guess, and why? (We don't give plain answers to questions that smell like homework and ndon't show effort.)

Comment: @Wouter : It is not home work, I am working with spyglass tool for cleaning cdc rule set, I have this module and as you can see, this module is used to prevent metastability. I am observing the error `data loss on same or fast to slow clock domain crossing` so what i guess is, it may false path so that it will not perform any timing checks on this path. If any standard constraints for this type of crossing is there then i want to know, nothing else.

Comment: If you haven't setup any timing constraints, there can't be any timing ignores or false paths. Can your tool generate a clock interaction report?

Comment: @Martin Zabel : Yeah sure!

Comment: What are the ports `srst_ni` and `drst_ni`? There seem to be not related to the design in the picture?

Comment: yes, It is simplified diagram so excluded, but actual RTL uses that resets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its source clock is `aclk` and target clock is `bclk`, `adat` should be the only false path here. Other paths are valid and don't require any special constraint.

The false path can be defined to the data input pin of the second register (the one between `adat` and `bdat1`). I don't know how your tool treats the register names, but I used Synopsys' naming convention in the following example.

```
set_false_path -to bdat1_reg/D
```

There is a second way to define this false path. If the clocks are defined asynchronous to each other, `adat` will be false path automatically. I assume `ACLK` and `BCLK` are previously defined clocks.

```
set_clock_groups -asynchronous -group ACLK -group BCLK
```

Answer (score 2):

A two flip-flop synchronizes can be constrained with the follwing XDC lines. XDC is a Xilinx flavor for the commonly known Synopsis Design Constraint files (SDC).

```
set_property ASYNC_REG true [get_cells -regexp {gen\[\d+\]\.Sync/FF2}]
set_property ASYNC_REG true [get_cells -regexp {gen\[\d+\]\.Sync/FF1_METASTABILITY_FFS}]
set_false_path -from [all_clocks] -to [get_pins -regexp {gen\[\d+\]\.Sync/FF1_METASTABILITY_FFS/D}]
```

Source: [sync_Bits_Xilinx.xdc](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/ucf/misc/sync/sync_Bits_Xilinx.xdc)

`FF1_METASTABILITY_FFS` is the first flip-flop (the meta stable one) and `FF2` is the second flip-flop.

---

A generic 2-FF synchronizer implementation can be found in our [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) as  [`PoC.misc.sync.Bits`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/misc/sync/sync_Bits.vhdl), as well as two vendor optimized implementations for [Xilinx](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/misc/sync/sync_Bits_Xilinx.vhdl) and [Altera](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/misc/sync/sync_Bits_Altera.vhdl). The above XDC code is relatively applied to all instances of `PoC.misc.sync.Bits` by setting the file property `SCOPED_TO_REF` to `sync_Bits_Xilinx`.

Comment: I think the constraints given by you is for XDC not for SDC, so if I do cdc analysis for two flop synchronizer within non-xillinx  platform like atrenta's spyglass, how should I constraint it?

Comment: `ASYNC_REG ` is also a verilog property `(*ASYNC_REG="true"*)` that you can write directly in the verilog code.